# LinkedList within a for doesn't work

Tags: java, string, vector, collections

If I run the lines all be good.

[image]

but if I run it there is a problem: **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2**
I don't understand how can there be a error if the code is doing what I wrote.

```
i=0 | y=0
i=0 | y=1
i=0 | y=2
Error EN HILO: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

Before these lines, I work with matrix in those lines, but I don't think that this affect the program.
[image]

Comment: `FILAS` is `ROWS`  =)

Comment: so what is the column if `FILAS` is row? In your OP, found that 2 loops on same `FILAS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing `INFOO` like this

```
INFOO=new Object[FILAS][CANDIDATE_DE_COLUMNES]
```

As here `CANDIDATE_DE_COLUMNES` is `<2` which is trowing exception for `y=2`

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `FILAS` is equal to 3.

It also helps to align and format code correctly.

The following loop should replicate your single lines.

```
for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<2;j++)
   {
       System.out.println(i + " <-> " + j);
   }
}
```

Comment: nope, because FILAS is generic, it depends of the longitud of the linkedlist. 

its a really weird. 
maybe because it is in a thread?

Comment: @MikeBrian step through the loop in the debugger.  It should show you what `FILAS` is and how many elements there actually are in `INFOO`.